# Верстка макета

Tags: photoshop, html, вёрстка, css

Привет.

У меня проблемы с версткой макета. Не получается создавать странички идентичные макету.
Может кто посоветует руководства для верстальщика для работы с Photoshop (как работать с шрифтами,картинками, и т д)?

Как определить на макете:

1. для строк `letter-spaccing,word-spacing,text-indent`
2. как вы определяете размер тени от блока.

Comment: По этому фотошоп для веба это прошлый век, в фигме css уже с коробки есть, и достаточно валидный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

оооо)Помню тоже от этого страдал. как таковых учебных руководств именно по процессу верстки нет. В этом случае достаточно простые шаги: учим Photoshop, оптимизацию изображений, учим `CSS` и `HTML`. Пробуем что-то делать. Посмотри ролики на YouTube, перелопачивай блоги верстальщиков. Есть книги "Мастерская CSS", "CSS. Рецепты програмиирования", "CSS. 100 и 1 совет".

Поищи в сети собрание видео-уроков "Видео-уроки по верстке сайта". Я уже не помню, кто автор, но там рассматривается вёрстка от получения макета до завершения этого процесса.

В общем, удачи в твоём пути!

**PS** `letter-spacing`, `text-indent` и остальные параметры текста надо смотреть в настройках опций элемента `Horizontal text`, но удобнее на панели `Символ`. Величину тени можно определить в стиле соответствующего слоя.

Comment: спасибо.Использую совет про видеоуроки

Answer (score 2):

У фотошопа есть замечательный инструмент Slice tool(K) им отмеряйте тень либо расстояние между строчками. Кликните дважды на выделенную область он и покажет расстояние в пикселях.
Я работаю именно так!
Также советую у мозилы есть дополнительный апплет называется pixel perfect. Когда отроете firebug, он появится на панели. Так вот делайте скриншот вашего макета, загоняете в pixel perfect даете прозрачность и накладываете поверх страницы. И тогда поверте нет ничего точнее чем по пиксельная верстка. Надеюсь я смог объяснить.

Comment: Pixel perfect в мозиле я настроил.Дело в том что не получается то4но верстку сделать.Различия местами в 3-5px.потом уже вручную через отступы корректирую.Наверно проблема что изначльно отступы неправильно измеряю

Comment: вы ресетер используете в своем CSS файле?

Comment: ДА.Халатность измерения возможно здесь причина

Comment: ну главное найти причину, измеряйте  Slice tool в фотошопе, ну и после применяйте в стиле. Различие может быть, для этого обязательно подключайте пиксель перфект, и смотрите на сколько идет разница у вас. Других методов увы я не знаю(

Comment: спасибо тебе большое.Обязательно заплюсую попоже

Comment: пожалуйста. Если найдешь решение отпиши мне самому будет интересно)

Comment: Скажите, а почему бы для замеров не использовать простую линейку? Правой кнопкой по пипетке в панели инструментов и там Ruler Tool.
С другой стороны включаем окошко window -> info. В его настройках выбираем пиксели. И в этом окне вам показывается результат замеров линейкой или кропа или выделения.

Comment: А что касается firebug`а, то рядом с закладочкой Style, есть еще layout. Там можно посмотреть все measures - измерения, которые получил блок. Аналогичное окно есть и для хрома, в его инструменте.

Answer (score 2):

Кстати, конкретно по **тенькам**. Да, безусловно, можно вытащить параметры из свойства слоя. Постоянный вопрос, как их преобразовать в нотацию css. Как раз попалась под руку статейка: [Recreating Photoshop Drop Shadows in CSS3 and Compass](http://heygrady.com/blog/2011/08/06/recreating-photoshop-drop-shadows-in-css3-and-compass/).
Сам еще не вникал, но судя по формулам используется mixin из компасса.

Вспоминая молодость вспоминаю проблемы с градиентами в PSD. Вот неплохой генератор, который понимает нотацию фотошопа по градиентам: [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

По шрифтам: [стэки](http://cssfontstack.com/), [font-face](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/vstraivaem-shrifty-pri-pomoshchi-font-squirrel-font-fac).

Все остальное, вроде, хорошо достается линейкой или пипеткой. И проверяется скриншотом :)

Comment: Казачок, если вас смущают слова mixin и compass, это функционал препроцессоров CSS. Фича, позваляющая работать с более удобным языком и синтаксисом для написания кода. Результатом компиляции такого кода является CSS-файл. Компасс - фреймворк для такого языка. Если вы только начали верстать, то лучше сначала хорошо разобраться с обыным CSS и потом уже разбираться с надстойками. Из статьи про тени вынесите для себя алгоритм преобразования.

Comment: Компасс - фреймворк для такого языка. Это что -то похожее на Less и SaSS?Ну а смысл их использовать если есть js?

Comment: Я может немного путаю терминологию слова "фреймворк", но да, компасс - фреймворк для sass/less. Одна из фич этой связки - использование своего рода функций, называемых mixin. Вы можете скормить этой функции параметры и она сгенерирует вам CSS-код. В случае с тенями вы берете 5 параметров из фотошопа, скармливаете этой функции и она отдает вам CSS-код готовой тени. JS здесь совершенно не причем.